# What is the most pythonic way to have a generator expression executed?

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, generator

More and more features of Python move to be "lazy executable", like generator
expressions and other kind of iterators.
Sometimes, however, I see myself wanting to roll a one liner "for" loop, just to perform some action.

What would be the most pythonic thing to get the loop actually executed?

For example:

```
a = open("numbers.txt", "w")
(a.write ("%d " % i) for i in xrange(100))
a.close()
```

Not actuall code, but you see what I mean. If I use a list generator, instead, I have the side effect of creating a N-lenght list filled with "None"'s.

Currently what I do is to use the expression as the argument in a call to "any" or to "all". But I would like to find a way that would not depend on the result of the expression performed in the loop - both "any" and "all" can stop depending on the expression evaluated.

To be clear, these are ways to do it that I already know about, and each one has its drawbacks:

```
[a.write ("%d " % i) for i in xrange(100))]

any((a.write ("%d " % i) for i in xrange(100)))

for item in (a.write ("%d " % i) for i in xrange(100)): pass
```

Comment: "N-length list filled with nuns."

Comment: Just to clarify: I seldom use things like this in production code - and given the reactions here, I probably will stop altogether. But I like to have fun writting one-liner things (althoug those are unpythonic by nature) -there is where I've been missing this the most.
Just yesterday, I went a great lenght trying ot get a one-liner for ruby's 1.9.2 "chunck" list method. (the one line version sucked - but one extra line declaring a dictionary before an "executed generator" gives Python something nicer than the "chunck" thing)

Comment: @Nas: Stop randomly accusing people of things they didn't do.

Comment: @jsbueno, for one-liners you want the Haskell forum: "sequence_ $ map print [0..99]". Mm mmm. :-)

Comment: There are no bad questions, there are only bad practices. 
To all haters out there: please stop downvoting anyone who dared answer! Knowledge is power - if you want `forbiden fruit` concept, you should do religion and not programming ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 2019 -
and this is a question from 2010 that keeps showing up. A [recent thread in one of Python's mailing lists spammed over 70 e-mails on this subject](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-ideas@python.org/thread/KMEX5FKXUJYSQ2WAEYLQYNQBOT2LBXCI/#KMEX5FKXUJYSQ2WAEYLQYNQBOT2LBXCI), and they refused again to add a `consume` call to the language.

On that thread, the most efficient mode to that actually showed up, and it is far from being obvious, so I am posting it as the answer here:

```py
import deque

consume = deque(maxlen=0).extend
```

And then use the `consume` callable to process generator expressions.

It turns out the `deque` native code in cPython actually is optimized for the `maxlen=0` case, and will just consume the iterable.
The `any` and `all` calls I mentioned in the question should be equally as efficient, but one has to worry about the expression truthiness in order for the iterable to be consumed.

---

I see this still may be controversial, after all, an explicit two line for loop can handle this - I remembered this question because I just made a commit where I create some threads, start then, and join then back - without a  `consume` callable, that is 4 lines with mostly boiler plate, and without benefiting from cycling through the iterable in native code:
https://github.com/jsbueno/extracontext/blob/a5d24be882f9aa18eb19effe3c2cf20c42135ed8/tests/test_thread.py#L27

Answer (score 10):

There is one obvious way to do it, and that is the way you should do it. There is no excuse for doing it a clever way.

```
a = open("numbers.txt", "w")
for i in xrange(100):
    a.write("%d " % i)
d.close()
```

Lazy execution gives you a serious benefit: It allows you to pass a sequence to another piece of code without having to hold the entire thing in memory. It is for the creation of efficient sequences as data types.

In this case, you do not want lazy execution. You want execution. You can just ... execute.  With a `for` loop.

Comment: In this case (writing to a file), it may be a good advice, but I often find use cases, where `for` cycle would be too much verbose. For example: `for a, b, c, d, e, f in an_iterable: my_function(a, b, c, d, e, f)` is quite long and it implies something more than mere application of a function to an iterable. Using something like: `exec_map(my_function, an_iterable)` is so much shorter and at least in my opinion, more elegant.

Answer (score 7):

If I wanted to do this specific example, I'd write

```
for i in xrange(100): a.write('%d ' % i)
```

If I often needed to consume an iterator for its effect, I'd define

```
def for_effect(iterable):
    for _ in iterable:
        pass
```

Comment: I think the for loop looks better over 2 lines. We like Python's indenty spaces

Comment: Yeah, I'd usually write it that way, too, but the OP might not have known of the one-line form, and specifically asked for one.

Answer (score 6):

There are many `accumulators` which have the effect of consuming the whole iterable they're given, such as `min` or `max` -- but even they don't ignore entirely the results yielded in the process (`min` and `max`, for example, will raise an exception if some of the results are complex numbers).  I don't think there's a built-in accumulator that does exactly what you want -- you'll have to write (and add to your personal stash of tiny utility function) a tiny utility function such as

```
def consume(iterable):
    for item in iterable: pass
```

The main reason, I guess, is that Python has a `for` statement and you're supposed to use it when it fits like a glove (i.e., for the cases you'd want `consume` for;-).

BTW, `a.write` returns `None`, which is falsish, so `any` will actually consume it (and `a.writelines` will do even better!).  But I realize you were just giving that as an example;-).

Comment: Actually, there *are* ways to accomplish what is asked for without the shortcoming of `min/max` - in one line and without creating list of len(N). I found 3 (three) distinct ways after a good night of sleep - but in the words of [Fermat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem) - 'This margin is too narrow to contain [this truly marvelous proof]' :-)

Comment: @Nas, there's obvious goofy ways such as `[x for x in iterable if False]` (makes an empty list) and the similar `any(x and False for x in iterable)` (doesn't make any list at all) and `all(x or True for x in iterable)` -- but (while they do fit just fine in this margin;-) they're all seriously cringe-worthy.

Comment: @Nas, well..feel free to use the main "page" instead of the margin then.  :-)

Comment: @Alex: Ah, very well - you mention one of the ways i thought of. About the other two you show - i wonder, are we guaranteed that bool(x) works for every type? (i assume this is about equivalent to being able to use object with operators `and/or/not`) ? PS. and no, i did not say i found any *pretty* or *pythonic* way

Comment: @jsbueno: Hmmm, i don't know - and got slapped again with votes down? Anyone throw a bounty bone? :)

Comment: @Nas, a (weird) type _might_ throw an exception in `__len__` (etc), you're right.  Plus, I'm not sure why I bothered coding them that way when the obvious simplification to `all(True for x in iterable)` etc avoids the risk _and_ is marginally faster;-).  (It's even [[slightly]] less cringe-inducing -- or maybe that's the effect of the beer I just had at the company's usual TGIF weekly meeting;-).