# Which python built-in object has the least size in memory?

Tags: python, object, size

```py
# On Python 3.9.2
>>> sys.getsizeof(None)
16
>>> sys.getsizeof(0)
24
>>> sys.getsizeof(True)
28
```

I just wanted to know if there is any object with its size less than the size of `None` object, i.e. less than 16 bytes.

Comment: The size of built-ins is an undefined part of Python. On my system running Python 3.3.3 the size of `None` is 8.

Comment: I believe that `None` has the smallest size. I know that also `Ellipsis` built in should have 16 bytes. But as @martineau said size of built ins is different across python versions

Comment: Perhaps you could make a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210238/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-python-types-programmatically) and test the size of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@quamrana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4834/quamrana), I tried to sort all the built-in objects based on their sizes and got into the following observation.
The code snippet I used:

```py
import builtins, sys, inspect

classes = [i for i in builtins.__dict__.values() if inspect.isclass(i)]
objects = []
for i in classes:
    try:
        objects.append((i, sys.getsizeof(i())))
    except:
        ...
objects.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
for i in objects[:10]:
    print(i)
```

And the stdout for the above snippet is:

```py
(<class 'object'>, 16)
(<class 'bool'>, 24)
(<class 'float'>, 24)
(<class 'int'>, 24)
(<class 'complex'>, 32)
(<class 'bytes'>, 33)
(<class 'tuple'>, 40)
(<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, 48)
(<class 'str'>, 49)
(<class 'bytearray'>, 56)
```

These are the 10 objects which has least size on Python 3.9.2 which runs on my machine.
As per [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau)'s comment, the size of each object varies across different python versions and machines.

Answer (score 2):

`None` will be the smallest usable object as far as I know irrespective of the system architecture, interpreter, versions.