# Drain or discard a generator without looping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

In an exception handler for a CSP style process, I need to read and discard the entire contents of a channel in order to allow other processes that are blocking to send to it to complete. The interface presents a generator for receiving, is there a faster way to consume and discard the entire contents of a generator than the following?

```
for _ in chan:
    pass
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209789/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-have-a-generator-expression-executed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way that is slightly faster:

```
collections.deque(chan, maxlen=0)
```

Your code makes the intention much clearer, though, so you should measure if there is a discernible difference.  I'd almost always prefer your code.

(I'd never use `_` as a variable name, though.  It tends to confuse people, clashes with `_` in the interactive shell and with the common `gettext` alias.)

**Edit**: Here are some simple timings:

```
In [1]: import collections

In [2]: a = range(100000)

In [3]: timeit reduce(lambda _, __: None, a)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.5 ms per loop

In [4]: timeit for dummy in a: pass
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.75 ms per loop

In [5]: timeit collections.deque(a, maxlen=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 ms per loop
```

Comment: `_` is a common name for a throwaway variable, I thought.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: In some languages it has a special meaning (e.g. Go). It has become abundant on SO, even for Python, but it is a bad idea to use it in Python.  It has no advantage to use such a name.  Call it `dummy` and you will avoid any confusion.

Comment: I'm only talking about Python; obviously this wouldn't apply to a language where there is an inherent meaning to the underscore. Personally I find it much clearer that a variable is intended to be a dummy variable if it's named with an underscore.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: There is no strong convention to use it in Python.  As far as I'm aware, it's not mentioned at all anywhere on `python.org`.  And I've been asked literally dozens of times what this strange syntax means.  Obviously nobody ever asked me why an unused variable is called `dummy` or `unused`.

Comment: Well, I can't cite a source for you, but I've been under the impression that it _is_ a fairly common convention.  I mean, if you have a statistical sample of Python code showing otherwise, then certainly I'm wrong, but I know what I've heard. (This is a separate issue from code clarity.)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: It certainly is rather common.  A few instances even appeared in Python's standard library.  But there is a difference between "it's common" and "it's a convention".  And there is certainly a difference between "it's common" and "it's a good idea".

Comment: Yeah, that's fair. It's not that important of a discussion, anyway (mostly irrelevant to the answer).

Comment: You could try `[x for x in a]` as well, but I don't think it would be faster. Worth a try though.

Comment: Rather than "_" as an unused variable name I tend to call it "unused" or "unused_whateveritis".

Comment: @LennartRegebro: It would be much, much faster to use `list(a)` instead of `[x for x in a]`.  I timed `list(a)` together with the above options (it's very fast!), but I did not include the timings because it creates an unneeded list with all the results, which might need a lot of memory in some cases.  I only included solutions  that send everything to the Orcus immediately.

Comment: The dequeue option is actually hand-optimized in the c implementation of dequeue: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cffe0467ab7b164739693598826bd3860f01b11f/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L356

Answer (score 1):

I've started using a deque that I can reuse if need be:

```
do_all = deque(maxlen=0).extend
```

Then I can consume generator expressions using:

```
do_all(poly.draw() for poly in model.polys)
```

Comment: But this isn't faster than `for poly in model.polys: poly.draw()`, nor is it more readable.  Why do you use it?  (This can be slightly faster to consume some iterable you already have, but explicitly constructing a generator just to consume it this way seems rather pointless to me.)

Comment: Is your comment based on an actual test, or gut feel? I've done some tests with this, and I get about 5% improvement, since do_all does the iterating in C, instead of iterating a Python variable `poly` (which must be guarded against any modifications in the body of the for loop). Most for loops it doesn't matter, but in my case, I am drawing *many*, many polys. (See my artwork at http://www.fractallography.com)

Comment: It's based on actual tests, many of which I did quite some time ago.  I just did the most basic ones again, see https://gist.github.com/1877613

Comment: "do_all does the iterating in C" -- not if you pass in a generator expression.  The generator expression creates a Python code object for the part that is supposed to be executed in every iteration.

Comment: I'll have to go back to look at the itertools module again, and see just what the heck Raymond Hettinger was talking about! Thanks for keeping me honest!

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
reduce(lambda _, __: None, chan)
```

But honestly I don't think you're going to do much better than the plain loop. "channel" suggests I/O which is going to be the bottleneck anyway.

Comment: Python has a fairly high function call overhead.  Calling a `lambda` function for every element is much slower than the bare for loop.

Comment: I added some simple timings to my answer.