# List comprehensions for side effects - idiomatically correct or an abomination?

Tags: python, idioms

I have a list of `cheese` objects. `Cheese` has a method that does a bunch of stuff with the db and whatnot, called `out_of_stock()`.

So:

```
[cheese.out_of_stock() for cheese in cheeses]
```

It feels sloppy to me. Like I'm doing something (creating a list) for a bunch of side effects (zeroing inventory).

Am I being foolish? Is this subjective to the method?

Comment: It seems very cheesey to me.

Comment: What does `out_of_stock` return? Do you need to look at the return code? Do you need to build a list of what it returns? Whether this is a bad idea depends on the answers.

Comment: that's a fair point; I think it's less wrong if there's a meaningful return value that you'll operate on later (as indicated in multiple answers)  but otherwise it's misuse of a list comprehension.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/9372429/753731

Comment: This question needs to be tagged so all Python users can read it! @cravoori That's a pretty good speed optimization but I wouldn't recommend it to anybody unless they absolutely need it or already know good python practices.

Comment: Be sure you don't get an out of cheese error. You'd have to redo from start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

List comprehensions are for creating a list. That's not what you're doing here, so I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I would do

```
for cheese in cheeses:
    cheese.out_of_stock()
```

This feels a bit more explicit to me. It's another line, but I suspect that another programmer reading that code would understand it well, whereas the list comprehension version might be slightly confusing. In addition, I could imagine that someone else might come along later (not knowing that `out_of_stock` doesn't return a value) and try to use that list later.

I guess there's nothing *wrong* with it, though. Ultimately, it comes down to who's going to be reading that code later (yourself or others) and whether or not they'll know what's going on.

EDIT: Also, you're using a lovely functional programming construct taken from Haskell to do nasty stateful things...

Comment: I agree with everything except for "I guess there is nothing wrong with it". In Python there should be one and preferably only one obvious way to do it.

Comment: You don't have to assign the list comprehension to a variable that could be misused later ;). But I agree the `for` loop is better.

Answer (score 3):

Semantically, if cheese.out_of_stock returned a boolean, then it would be fine.  However this is not very recommended if cheese.out_of_stock does not return a value, then it would be very confusing and unmaintainable.

```
import this
```

for more information

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions are usually used for filtering (or something similar where the result of the comprehsion is being used later) but not for replacing a loop calling a method on the iteration data. So this works but it locks ugly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing something with the return values of `cheese.out_of_stock()` this is perfectly Pythonic. If you are discarding the result of the list comprehension, it is bad style.

Creating the list is a waste of time and memory, just use the two line `for` loop from [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11771154/174728)

Answer (score 1):

```
for cheese in cheeses: cheese.out_of_stock()
```

Still a one liner and avoids the side effect of creating an unnecessary list.

Comment: This is even more ugly...heard of PEP8 ?

Comment: (c.__getattribute__('out_of_stock').__call__() for c in cheeses).  Look! no unnecessary list!

Comment: @Justanotherdunce +1 :) now you just need to iterate through that!

Answer (score 1):

The answer hinges entirely on whether you want the list. A list comprehension is often a good replacement for a loop like this:

```
stock = []
for cheese in cheeses:
   stock.append(cheese.out_of_stock())
```

But rarely if ever for a loop like this:

```
for cheese in cheeses:
    cheese.out_of_stock()
```

When people read a list comprehension, they don't typically expect it to have side effects - aside from something like cacheing that doesn't affect the meaning of the program, and, of course, building a list. Certainly, any side effects it has shouldn't be necessary for your program's correctness - this also means they can be worth avoiding for the first type of loop if you're using an API without [command-query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation) - that is, even if you *do* want the list, if `.out_of_stock()` *also* has side-effects that you depend on, you should consider using the loop rather than the comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, don't do it.

There is a quite similar way of doing it that is not ugly. It requires a pre-defined function like this:

```
def consume(iter):
    for i in iter:
        pass
```

Now you can write code like this:

```
consume(cheese.out_of_stock() for cheese in cheeses)
```

So really, this is just Peters suggestion wrapped in a function which is called with a generator expression. And though much better than the list comprehension, it's still not exactly beautiful. It would really be best (most explicit) to just use the for loop directly.